# Unsureness about passing EndPoint to Socket.ReceiveFrom()

Tags: c#, sockets, reference, udp, endpoint

If I do something like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint remote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("12.34.56.78"), 1337);
sock.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref remote);
```

Will the ReceiveFrom method only receive packets from the endpoint that is being passed? The documentation states the following:

> With connectionless protocols, ReceiveFrom will read the first
>   enqueued datagram received into the local network buffer.

Does that mean that the passed EndPoint is only used for storing the EndPoint of the host the packet has come from and does not affect the ReceiveFrom method's behaviour at all? If so, why does it need to be passed as "ref" instead of "out"?

Comment: After doing several tests I've figured out that the passed end point's value does not matter. It's only used for storage. But I still don't know why it has to be passed as reference then.

Comment: Isn't EndPoint a struct?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Although that shouldn't make a difference in my case.

Comment: It might work better using sock.ReceiveFrom() instead of the listed remote.ReceiveFrom().

Comment: Why am I always making those stupid typoes? That's what I meant to do, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `ReceiveFrom` method is a managed wrapper for [recvfrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinSock function. This function takes a pointer to `sockaddr` structure that is optional and allocated/deallocated on the caller side.

With that in mind I have a few theories why is the `EndPoint` passed as `ref` and not `out`:

1. Maybe for the consistency with WinSock function the `EndPoint` is allocated by the caller and therefore passed by `ref`.
2. Maybe `EndPoint` was at some point considered to be an optional parameter, but this was never implemented (I checked, it must be non-null).
3. Maybe for some protocols there are processing directions passed through the `EndPoint` parameter. Maybe even future protocols :-)