# 'ipAddr.ScopeId' threw an exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, exception, udp

[image]
[image]

```
string ipAddress = "a.b.c.d";
IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, port);
EndPoint remote = (EndPoint)endPoint;
socket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref remote);
```

I have an intermittent problem, when I am trying to read data from a UDP socket. I tell it which IP address and port I want to read from - rarely, a packet from a different IP address is received under this one?

The silent exception (when I hover over ipAddr) is:

> 'ipAddr.ScopeId' threw an exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'

If I catch this whilst debugging, and I look at the objects 'endPoint' and 'remote' - endpoint is the correct ip address, but the ip address of remote has changed (of its own accord after this exception, this is NOT a problem with my logic) to the actual ip address it received from, but not the one that it requested from!

ReceiveFrom works 99% of the time, what does this exception mean, why Microsoft why?

The problem is, once that packet is read, it is read, and not passed onto where ever it was meant to go, how can I prevent this?

edit: scopeID is for IPV6, but I don't care for ipv6 so maybe I am looking in the wrong place, but this still doesnt explain why 'endpoint' is not properly resolved to 'remote' (IPEndPoint cast to abstract EndPoint) -- 172.50.2.111 doesnt exist and 99% of the time it times out, but why is it picking up other packets?! *cries*

Comment: Are you binding the socket (socket.Bind) to the proper endpoint on your local machine?

Comment: It is bound to IPAddress.Any - I want to receive from multiple IP Addresses, but I only want to read from the ip address i ask to read from - once its been taken its taken i dont want to cause packets to disappear - please see screenshot edit added above and tell me that doesn't boggle your mind also

Comment: From the MSDN documentation: "With connectionless protocols, ReceiveFrom will read the first enqueued datagram received into the local network buffer.", maybe it always does this and the actual ipaddress/port you send it is moot, it will just give you whatever is in the buffer regardless of which endpoint it came from, which kind of makes sense as it's being passed by reference.

Comment: @Matthew - Thanks!! after searching for your quote I also came across: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180328/unsureness-about-passing-endpoint-to-socket-receivefrom

Comment: Please see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180328/unsureness-about-passing-endpoint-to-socket-receivefrom